# Why loop is so faster?

Tags: cpu, compiler-optimization

The following loop in fortran almost takes no time

```
j=0
do i=1,1000000000000000000
    j=j+1
end do
print*,j
```

But I just don't understand, our cpu is about GHz, which means 10^9 cycle in a second, while the above loop cycle is way too much than 10^9, why it almost takes no time?

It seems that the values is not computed at compiled time. We can add outer loop, until

```
do m=1,1000000000
do i=1,1000000000000000000
    j=j+1
end do
end do
print*,j
```

Now it takes a second on my computer

**Edit**

I am using windows, intel parallel studio 15, with no extra compilation option: simply `ifort test.f90`. Timing method is simple, just wait after I press Enter in command line to execute the .exe

Comment: Would the compiler be optimizing your code? Are you able to read the resulting assembly code?

Comment: @bolov I am sure the values is not computed at compiled time. Because if we keep on adding outer loop gradually, it will takes time

Comment: @AbdullahNehir I don't know how to read assembly code

Comment: @user15964 You have to provide additional information in order for people to give good answers. At least, you need to mention the compiler, the version of the compiler, the compilation options being used to compile the code, the target architecture and the technique you're using to measure running time. Also even if you don't know how to read assembly, it would be nice if you generated the assembly code yourself and append it to the question.

Comment: @HadiBrais Hi, Hadi Brais, thank you for attention.  I update the information. In terms of assembly, I currently has no time to learn how to get assembly, I may add it if I have time to come back.

Comment: @HadiBrais I want to add, if I don't add `print*,j` in the last line, no matter how many layers of loops I added, the program takes no time. It seems that the compiler is smart enough and knows that I am not outputing anything, then it just doesn't do any calcuation.

Answer (score 1):

don't know fortran, but if this would be C, the compiler could optimize the above code removing the loop altogether as the value of `j` can be computed at compile time.

So the above code would be reduced to

```
print 1000000000000000000
```

---

Your logic about cycles and instructions is flawed. Modern CPUs parallelize code on hardware level, even if the code is serial:

- a cpu has more a few ALU who can compute arithmetic instructions in parallel
- instructions are executed in a pipeline, so at any one point, different stages of consecutive instructions are executed in parallel.

So "max of one instruction per cycle" doesn't hold.

Also `increment by one` is one of the fastest instruction in the CPU.

Comment: Thank you, bolov. But `do m=1,1000000000` Plus `do i=1,1000000000000000000` is 10^18 times of G, this surely can't account all the thing you have listed.

Comment: What is ASM? A book?

Comment: Oh, understand, Thank you